# How to upload an image from a URL using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I want users to be able to add a photo to a page by giving its URL.  I want to both display it and save the image on my server.  Can I do this using AJAX, and ideally with Jquery?

I'm currently using the Jquery File Upload plugin to handle uploads from the user's computer, however I could not find a way of using it to handle upload by URL.

Comment: Yes you can do this. AJAX the URL of the image up to your server-side script that downloads the image, and then add the image code on the client browser.

Comment: couldn't you add the photo to the page just by writing in an img tag with that URL as the src?  -- just saw your edit, you want to save it to your server too.  That would have to be done on the back-end.

Comment: I just edited the question to say that I want to save the image too.  Otherwise displaying it by writing out the img tag would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just a URL, you can send the URL to the server and make it download the image, instead of sending the whole image in AJAX.

Comment: What happens if it's a local url?